# Visual Cobol 2010 and eclipse

Tags: java, cobol

I am trying to run simple Java Program Hello World which has a call to simple Cobol Subroutine hello.cbl

The instructions in Visual Cobol documents say to first load library. I do understand, how do i load this library. I have build the project and Eclipse has created one hello.idy file.
Should this file be in the class path of my Java program. How do i load this library.
I am using Visual COBOL 2010 with Eclipse and on Windows.

Any help on this would be very valuable

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Micro Focus community forum @ http://community.microfocus.com/Forums/3_COBOL__Net_Express_Server_Express_Visual_COBOL
 thought it is holiday season..